# generation of fermions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, standard-model, higgs

a random idea struck my head today, and i'd like to know, if it's any good, or why not, or if there is actually some research / paper about that already

so i was wondering:

> we know that there are 3 generations of fermions, all with the same properties only differing in mass (and their characterizing baryon- or lepton-numbers)
>
> what if all three generations are actually just one generation, but interacting with the higgs in 3 different ways?

(of course i haven't come up with a suitable mechanism)

also the question seems so elementary, that someone *must* have worked on that already.

if yes,

- is there any model that tries to do this fitting 3 -> 1?
- can it be made logically coherent?

  - if yes, is it just equivalent to the current standard model?
  - or does it yield new particles?

any thoughts as always very much appreciated!

Comment: I don't know what the difference between "there are three generations and they differ by mass" and "there is one generation, and its members differ by mass" is supposed to be.

Comment: The question might be re-phrased: Why are there 3 generations of matter?  http://www.symmetrymagazine.org/article/august-2015/the-mystery-of-particle-generations.  According to the linked article from Fermilab/SLAC, currently it's unknown why each generation reacts differently with the Higgs particle.  Richard Ruiz (https://www.ippp.dur.ac.uk/profile/rruiz) is studying the origins of mass difference among 3 generations of neutrinos. He says, “There is a pattern here staring at us but we cannot quite figure out how to make sense of it.”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean exactly by "interact differently with the Higgs"? I can come up with two reasonable definitions:

1. Some difference in the internal structure makes them interact differently. In this case this very difference is called "generation", so nothing new here.
2. The mode of the interaction is somehow chosen spontaneously. I am almost 100% sure that in this case the model is inconsistent with observations.

Anyway, this questions needs clarification.

Comment: i think the answer is, i need to think a bit more about it!
thanks for your thoughts